# IBM tutorial for RSS reader for Android not working

Tags: android, html, css

The IBM tutorial here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/ is not working. It's crashing saying that 'The app quit unexpectedly.'

Has anybody got it working?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow this manual but I didn't like it. It would be better that you try to refer to this source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/donut-release/tests/AndroidTests/src/com/android/unit_tests/SafeSaxTest.java

It's the same than ibm manual but in this manual there was an example using android.sax and you don't need to add any java library.

There other way to read a RSS. You can do it using a XmlPullParser: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't want to handle RSS code by yourself, you can use a third party RSS library such as this one:
https://github.com/Pkmmte/PkRSS

It practically takes care of all RSS loading/parsing so you don't have to worry about it.